# Converting the "long" data type to string/text in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-7

I'm looking to convert the data type of a field from `long` to `text`. I have a field with the mapping

```
"shopId": {
  "type": "long"
}
```

I first iserted some documents like:

```
{"shopId": "25"},{"shopId": "26"},{"shopId": "27"}
```

I then added another field with the type `text`:

```
{
  "anotherShopId":{
    "type":"text",
    "fields":{
      "keyword":{
        "type":"keyword",
        "ignore_above":256
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So now my mapping/schema look like this:

```
{
  "sanchitindex":{
    "aliases":{
      
    },
    "mappings":{
      "properties":{
        "anotherShopId":{
          "type":"text",
          "fields":{
            "keyword":{
              "type":"keyword",
              "ignore_above":256
            }
          }
        },
        "shopId":{
          "type":"long"
        }
      }
    },
    "settings":{
      "index":{
        "creation_date":"1612778764965",
        "number_of_shards":"1",
        "number_of_replicas":"1",
        "uuid":"S0iqrEIKS96XMnRgXkGsiQ",
        "version":{
          "created":"7030199"
        },
        "provided_name":"sanchitindex"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to migrate the `shopId` values to `anotherShopId` using the Reindex API.

```
POST http://localhost:9200/sanchitindex/_reindex

    {
      "source": {
        "index": "shopId"
      },
      "dest": {
        "index": "anotherShopId"
      },
      "script": {
        "inline": "ctx._source.shopId = String.valueOf(ctx._source.shopId)"
      }
    }
```

But I was not able to do so as I'm getting the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [sanchitindex] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, _reindex]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [sanchitindex] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, _reindex]"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Version: 7.3.1

Is there any other way to migrate the data from `long` to `text`?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're targeting `POST http://localhost:9200/_reindex` [(without the index name)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) instead of `POST .../sanchitindex/_reindex`.

The above was an attempt to add a new [`_type`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-type-field.html) called "_reindex" which collides with the [requirement](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) of one mapping type per index, thus the error message stating that

> the final mapping would have more than 1 type